# Laravel handling form with variable number of elements

Tags: php, laravel-4

I need to get a variable number of nursing factors (input text) dynamically created on a form. How the controller can handle this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use HTML input arrays:

```
<input type="text" name="fields['name']" ... >
<input type="text" name="fields['age']" ... >
<input type="text" name="fields['address']" ... >
```

And in your controller you will grab an array via:

```
$arrayOfFields = Input::get('fields');
```